# can't find up down switch in logisim

Tags: switch-statement

I'm using logisim evolution on macOS, I could not find this switch [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jnNf.png)when I search I found that the Switch is in the Input/Output Extra folder and I did not found this too. so please help where can I find this switch